# $f(x)\in R[0,\pi]$,how to prove that he following two inequalities cannot be held together?$\int_{0}^{\pi}|f(x)-\sin x|^{2}dx\leqslant \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f(x)\in R[0,\pi]$(Riemann integrable),how to prove that he following two inequalities cannot be held together?
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}|f(x)-\sin x|^{2}dx\leqslant \frac{3}{4}$$ $$\int_{0}^{\pi}|f(x)-\cos x|^{2}dx\leqslant \frac{3}{4}$$
I use Minkowski inequalities to solve this problem.From Minkowski inequalities,I know:
$$\sqrt{3}\geqslant \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi}|f(x)-\sin x|^{2}dx}+\sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi}|f(x)-\cos x|^{2}dx}\geq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin x-\cos x|^{2}dx}=\sqrt{\pi}$$,which leads to contradiction.

But if I don't want to use Minkowski inequalities,how can I solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any special inequality. Just expand the integral and you will find the sum of the two integrals equals to
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\pi \{2f(x)^2 - 2(\sin x +\cos x) +1 \}\,dx 
& = \int_0^\pi \left\{2\left(f(x)-\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{2}\right)^2 + 1 - \frac{(\sin x + \cos x)^2}{2} \right\}\,dx \\
& \geq \int_0^\pi \left\{\frac{1}{2} - \sin x \cos x \right\}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}> \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} 
\end{align*}
Therefore, we cannot have the two inequalities hold together.